# trying to change background of imageButton in List item

Tags: android, listview, imagebutton, onitemclick

**Objective**

I want to play sound on click of List item with ImageButton (initially hidden, visible on click) showing play pause (2 images) resource.
ImageButton is only to show state of sound to user.

**Problem**

When I scroll the List, imageButton is again GONE.

**Code**

*BaseAdapter*

```
    private class ListAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    private Context mContext;
    private LayoutInflater mInflater;
    ViewHolder holder;

    ListAdapter(Context context) {
        mContext = context;
        this.mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(mContext);

    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return indexTitles.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return indexTitles.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ViewHolder holder;
        if (convertView == null) {
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.dua_row, null);
            holder.mainBg = (RelativeLayout) convertView.findViewById(R.id.duaBG);
            holder.title_text = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.title_text);
            holder.buttonPlayPause = (ImageButton) convertView.findViewById(R.id.imageButton);
            holder.buttonPlayPause.setFocusable(false);
            holder.buttonPlayPause.setFocusableInTouchMode(false);
            convertView.setTag(holder);
        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }
        String leftRemoved = indexTitles.get(position).trim();
        holder.title_text.setText(leftRemoved);
        // /player selection
        if (playPos == position) {
            holder.buttonPlayPause.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.buttonpause);
            holder.mainBg.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#000000"));
            holder.title_text.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#D59D52"));
        } else {
            holder.buttonPlayPause.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            holder.title_text.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#000000"));
            holder.mainBg.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#D59D52"));
        }
        return convertView;
    }
```

*List Row*

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_margin="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:id="@+id/duaBG"
android:background="#D59D52">

<TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="32dp"
    android:text=""
    android:textSize="18dp"
    android:id="@+id/title_text"
    android:ellipsize="end"
    android:maxLines="1"

    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/imageButton"
    android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/imageButton" />

<ImageButton
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/imageButton"
    android:focusable="false"
    android:visibility="gone"
    android:background="@drawable/buttonpause"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />

<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="5dp"
    android:background="#000000"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"></LinearLayout>
```

*OnItemClickListener*

```
// indexTitles is ArrayList<String>
    indexTitles = getIndexTitles();
    final ListAdapter adapter = new ListAdapter(this);
    listView.setAdapter(adapter);
    listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {


        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            final View v = view.findViewById(R.id.imageButton);
            v.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

            if (mediaPlayer.isPlaying() && playPos == position) {
                // pause mediaplayer
                mediaPlayer.pause();
                MEDIA_PAUSED = true;
                v.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.buttonplay);

            } else if (MEDIA_PAUSED && !mediaPlayer.isPlaying() && playPos == position) {
                MEDIA_PAUSED = false;
                mediaPlayer.start();
                v.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.buttonpause);
            } else if (!mediaPlayer.isPlaying() || mediaPlayer.isPlaying() && playPos != position) {
                // release and start from this position
                mediaPlayer.reset();
                v.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                v.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.buttonpause);
                String s = String.format("%03d", position + 2);
                String Path = SDCARD_PATH + "/DoaData/DD_" + s + ".mp3";
                playPos = position;
                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                File file = new File(Path);
                Uri uri = Uri.fromFile(file);
                try {
                    mediaPlayer.setDataSource(context, uri);
                    mediaPlayer.prepare();
                    mediaPlayer.start();
                    mediaPlayer.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
                            v.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.buttonplay);
                        }
                    });
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    });
```

**What Needed**
I want to imageButton to keep its state about being played or paused.

**Thanks**

Comment: what is playPos ? where  u are getting that

Comment: add `holder.buttonPlayPause.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);` in if statement when `playPos == position` for more info : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11945563/how-listviews-recycling-mechanism-works

Comment: @ V V the playPos is int coming from onClick position...

Comment: thanks @shayanpourvatan it helped

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply set the visibility inside the **IF** statement like this:

```
   if (playPos == position) {           
         holder.buttonPlayPause.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
         // further implementation
    } else {
        holder.buttonPlayPause.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        // further implementation
    }
```

The problem occured, because the list adapter recycles the old views. When one view is not visible and the list is creating the new view using an old one, you have to set every different property again, else all properties from the previous view object are recycled/reused.

Answer (score 0):

I have done it, with the help @Thomas and @shayan

this is how I changed my code to get what I needed

```
        @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ViewHolder holder;
        if (convertView == null) {
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.dua_row, null);
            holder.mainBg = (RelativeLayout) convertView.findViewById(R.id.duaBG);
            holder.title_text = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.title_text);
            holder.buttonPlayPause = (ImageButton) convertView.findViewById(R.id.imageButton);
            holder.buttonPlayPause.setFocusable(false);
            holder.buttonPlayPause.setFocusableInTouchMode(false);
            convertView.setTag(holder);
        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }
        String leftRemoved = indexTitles.get(position).trim();
        holder.title_text.setText(leftRemoved);
        // /player selection
        if (playPos == position) {
            if(MEDIA_PAUSED){
                holder.buttonPlayPause.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.buttonplay);
            } else if(!MEDIA_PAUSED)  {
                holder.buttonPlayPause.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.buttonpause);
            }

            holder.mainBg.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#000000"));
            holder.title_text.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#D59D52"));
            holder.buttonPlayPause.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        } else {
            holder.buttonPlayPause.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            holder.title_text.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#000000"));
            holder.mainBg.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#D59D52"));
        }
        return convertView;
    }
```

And Changed onItemClick() like this

```
try {
                    mediaPlayer.setDataSource(context, uri);
                    mediaPlayer.prepare();
                    mediaPlayer.start();
                    MEDIA_PAUSED = false;

                    getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);

                    mediaPlayer.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
                            v.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.buttonplay);
                            getWindow().clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);

                        }
                    });
```